# Increase speed of replica fetch in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there anyway I can speed up the rate at which the  replicas will fetch data from leader?

I am using bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh to test the throughput of my producer. And I have set a client quota of 50 MBps. Now without any replicas I am getting throughput ~ 50MBps but when replication factor is set to 3, it reduces to ~30 MBps.

There is no other traffic in the network so I am not sure why things are slowing down. Is there some parameter like replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes, replica.fetch.min.bytes that needs to be tuned to achieve high throughput? How can I speed up my replicas?

Comment: There's a lot of factors here but batching produce requests is a big one. Another one is num.replica.fetchers is default to 1. The other parameters you mentioned also play a role. Try varying some parameters and instrument the broker for JMX so you can see your specific bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

increasing value of   `num.replica.fetchers` should help, its Number of threads used to replicate messages from leaders. Increasing this value can increase the degree of I/O parallelism in the follower broker. default value 1